# Autobahn component with .NET router (WampSharp)

Tags: python, autobahnws, wampsharp

At the moment I'm playing with the WAMP proto, and I'm curious if something like this is possible, because I can't get it to work:

1.Having WAMP router written in c# (WampSharp) :

```
const string location = "ws://127.0.0.1:9999/wsdemo";

try
{
    using (IWampHost host = new DefaultWampHost(location))
    {
        IWampHostedRealm realm = host.RealmContainer.GetRealmByName("realm1");
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host is running on : " + location);
    }
}
catch(Exception exc)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error : " + exc.ToString());
}
```

2.Having component written in python :

```
import random
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks
from autobahn.twisted.util import sleep
from autobahn.twisted.wamp import ApplicationSession, ApplicationRunner

class Component(ApplicationSession):
    """
    An application component that publishes events with no payload
    and with complex payload every second.
    """

    @inlineCallbacks
    def onJoin(self, details):
        print("session attached")

        counter = 0
        while True:
            num = random.randint(0, 100)
            print("publishing : com.myapp.topic1", num)
            self.publish(u'com.myapp.topic1', num)
            counter += 1
            yield sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    runner = ApplicationRunner(url=u"ws://127.0.0.1:9999/wsdemo", realm=u"realm1")
    runner.run(Component)
```

When I run python script, I'm getting the error :

```
2017-02-20T19:49:46+0100 Main loop terminated.
2017-02-20T19:49:46+0100 Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-02-20T19:49:46+0100   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Educational Edition 1.0.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2199, in <module>
2017-02-20T19:49:46+0100     globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
2017-02-20T19:49:46+0100   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Educational Edition 1.0.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1638, in run
2017-02-20T19:49:46+0100     pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
2017-02-20T19:49:46+0100   File "D:/Programming/Astronomy/Dev/ZenithPlatform/backbone/local/tests/wamp.py", line 41, in <module>
2017-02-20T19:49:46+0100     runner.run(Component)
2017-02-20T19:49:46+0100   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\autobahn\twisted\wamp.py", line 312, in run
2017-02-20T19:49:46+0100     raise connect_error.exception
2017-02-20T19:49:46+0100 twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError: Connection was refused by other side: 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it..
```

As per http://autobahn.ws/python/wamp/programming.html#running-a-wamp-router

> The component we’ve created attempts to connect to a WAMP router
>   running locally which accepts connections on port 8080, and for a
>   realm realm1.
>
> Our suggested way is to use Crossbar.io as your WAMP router. There are
>   other WAMP routers besides Crossbar.io as well.

Could something like this be achieved at all?

Thanks,
Civa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *using* statement disposes the router before the program ends.

Just add a Console.ReadLine(); statement inside the using scope after the Console.WriteLine() statement. That should work.

Comment: Oh, Dear Lord... :D Completely overlooked that, when I quickly copied demo code to win app. Many thanks!